# Can ng-model race with custom directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible for ng-model and ng-enter (a custom directive that simply changes enter key behaviour to call the provided function) to race in the event of rapid input?  (in this case a barcode scanner with a keyboard wedge driver, so far faster than a person could type.)

example in view:

```
<input ng-enter="create()" maxlength="16"class="input" ng-model="data.person.idNumber" required/>
```

In controller

```
    $scope.create = function(){
        var idNumber= $scope.data.person.idNumber;
//call server etc
```

We're seeing incidents where partial numbers get uploaded and I'm wondering if it could be that not all the data-binds are done when the value gets copied to the function scoped var.

[From here where @joyBlanks steered me](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) it seems to call out ngSubmit as being special in waiting for pending binds, so perhaps we infer from omission that there's no particular ordering for directives in general.

Comment: There might be a case. You can play or checkout debounced in angular

Comment: might try wrapping in `$timeout`

Comment: `ng-enter` is not an angularjs provided directive so I can't be sure what it does but it seems to just call your scope function inside of a scope.$apply when invoked. And yes, there can be a condition where not all of the values that were typed are in the model before it is invoked.  You can do like @charlietfl suggested and do a `$timeout` inside your `create` function to allow the changes to propogate

Comment: There is an ordering for when directives get linked but the problem that you are having is because of the state of the variables based on the different event handlers.  There is one that is almost immediately invoked after you press the enter key and there is another one that is almost immediately invoked when you change the value of the input (with maybe more delay because it does more work).  The ordering of these events is not necessarily guaranteed.

Comment: Another thing, all of the "data-binds" WILL be done "when the value gets copied to the function scoped var", BUT your `create` function *may* still be called before all of this occurs